# How to locate the element which has only one attribute and is duplicate with other elements in the webpage?

Tags: html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

```
<html>
<tr id="userman-orgchart-tree-node-9" class="fancytree-expanded fancytree-folder fancytree-has-children fancytree-exp-e fancytree-ico-ef">
<td>
<span class="fancytree-node" style="padding-left: 16px;">
<span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
<span class="fancytree-icon"></span>
<span class="fancytree-title">Legal</span>
</span>
</tr>
<tr id="userman-orgchart-tree-node-10" class="fancytree-active fancytree-folder fancytree-has-children fancytree-exp-c fancytree-ico-cf">
<td>
<span class="fancytree-node" style="padding-left: 16px;">
<span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
<span class="fancytree-icon"></span>
<span class="fancytree-title">Branch Performance Test</span>
</span>
</tr>
</html>
```

Here, in the above case how do I write an element locator to identify the span for **Branch Performance Test** taking in consideration that **tr id** could dynamically keep changing to **11 or 12** by adding another record between.

Comment: Which span element do you want to locate wrt text??

Comment: I want to locate the element with the text Branch Performance Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//span[@class='fancytree-title' and text()='Branch Performance Test']/ancestor::span
```

Above will return all span ancestors of a span with conditions

OR

```
//span[@class='fancytree-title' and text()='Branch Performance Test']/parent::span
```

Above will return first span parent of a span with conditions

Comment: Mikhail- Is there a way to combineboth branch element id and the element id for the downward arrow so that I could click on downward arrow for that specific Branch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292910/is-there-a-way-to-combine-both-branch-element-id-and-the-element-id-for-the-down