# Is there a way to combine both branch element id and the element id for the downward arrow?

Tags: css, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Is there a way to combine both branch element id and the element id for the downward arrow so that I could click on downward arrow for that specific Branch?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stay on the common "tr" level - getting the desired row by the "fancytree title" and then going down to the arrow-down "button":

```
//tr[.//span[@class = "fancytree-title" and . = "Branch 100"]]//span[@class = "userman-menu"]
```

Comment: tried using this as well:
//tr[span[@class = 'fancytree-title' and text()= 'Branch 100']//span[@class = 'userman-menu']]
it didn't work.

Comment: @SaiKiran okay, one more try - I've updated the expression, give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: //tr[.//span[@class = "fancytree-title" and text()= "Branch 100"]//span[@class = "userman-menu"]]
added a square brace missing that starts after 'tr' and tried with this way too.. Doesnt work..

Comment: @SaiKiran ah, sorry, I had the square brace missing - but it should be closed in a different place - fixed, give it a try. Thanks.